# interchanging the positions within 5 objects coordinate in opengl

Tags: opengl

[image]I have drawn  5 squares with different coordinates in opengl...and now what I want to do is to interchange the positions of those 5 square coordinates within itself ...for example: if I click the blue square it should  move on to red position (blue to red) similarly red to pink, pink to white, white to blue.
can anyone help me please!!!
THANKS IN ADVANCE

can you help us with any formula to be used to interchange the above explained positions....or with any source code to do such operation.

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you running into trouble? Please add more details about how you've set up your scene.

Comment: Interchanging the squares could be as simple as swapping their colors & redrawing the scene. But OpenGL only handles graphics. I/O stuff like click detection depends on what else you are using (OS, other libraries, engines, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so first of all, you'll have to write some kind of collision detection with cursor that can identify what square you are clicking on.

I'm not sure if I understand, do you want one square to be moved on top of the stack when drawn, or move in position?

Now, there are a couple ways to determine which object gets drawn on top of another. You could, when giving each object coordinates, have them drawn based on their z value by enabling the depth testing.

If you want to move the object, the simplest way, is also kinda complex. You need to deal with matrices. https://learnopengl.com/#!Getting-started/Transformations gives a pretty good example of them, and the following tutorial gives a bunch of example code. It's ok, if you don't fully grasp the math, as there are plenty of math libraries that will do the hard work for you.

Comment: Too broad questions make too broad answers. If you have to write "I'm not sure if I understand", you should ask the OP to clarify the question before answering :)